# FragmentManager crashes when using Replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, mono, xamarin.android

I have an Activity and few Fragments. I have to replace fragment in FrameLayout. But when I'm using this function my app crashes.
Here is the code of function

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {

            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
            var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.Commit();

            mDrawerList.SetItemChecked (position, true);
            SetTitle (mScreenTitles [position]);
            mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer (mDrawerList);
        } else {
            Log.Error (this.Class.Name, "Error, fragment not created");
        }
```

And here is an error:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at --- End of managed
>   exception stack trace --- at java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) at Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   at ... 1 more at Caused by:
>   md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable:
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Android.OS.BaseBundle'
>   from assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065'. at
>   Android.Views.View.n_OnSaveInstanceState (intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in
>   /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mavericks-monodroid-5.1-series/d23da369/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-19/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:14822
>   at at (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   object.e0a03ea8-44fe-4482-bf92-bc99edac0352 (intptr,intptr) at at
>   md5d7f0962782a324dbc9992a12c8322ca0.PagerSlidingTabStrip.n_onSaveInstanceState(Native
>   Method) at at
>   md5d7f0962782a324dbc9992a12c8322ca0.PagerSlidingTabStrip.onSaveInstanceState(PagerSlidingTabStrip.java:86)
>   at at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:13550) at
>   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2859)
>   at at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2865)
>   at at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:13533) at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:1639)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1023)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1233)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:696)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
>   at at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
>   at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) at ... 4
>   more

Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradientshape">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="УНИИ-ИТ, 1 курс, 11 - ПГ"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
        <TextView
            android:text="понедельник, 11 мая"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dayOfMonth"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:gravity="center" />
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:fadingEdge="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also i load the fragment layout for fragments in viewPager.
 Here is it:

```
<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/LessonsView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

And layout of ListView items in ViewPager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border">
        <TextView
            android:text="   1"
            android:id="@+id/PairNumber"
            android:layout_width="35.5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/triangle"
            android:alpha="0.8"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="Инновационный менеджмент и развитие информационных технологий"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pairTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:textColor="#ff000000" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Лекция"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pairType"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:textColor="#ff949494" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#ffe5e8ea"
        android:alpha="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:minWidth="45px"
        android:minHeight="115px"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="-1dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon_teacher"
            android:layout_width="35.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="Миленко"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/Teacher"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:background="#ffe5e8ea"
        android:alpha="1" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
        android:minWidth="45px"
        android:minHeight="115px"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/icon_place"
            android:layout_width="35.5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:adjustViewBounds="false"
            android:cropToPadding="false"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
            <TextView
                android:text="Корпус:1, Аудитория 314"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/pairPlace"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textColor="#ff000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:minWidth="45px"
        android:minHeight="45px">
        <TextView
            android:text="20:15-21:45"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/pairTime"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:background="@drawable/timebackground"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#ff000000" />
        <Button
            android:text="Напоминать"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/NotifyBtn"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonbackground"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/button_notify_inactive"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:alpha="0.9" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please include the layout xml code?

Comment: @MattR ,Added viewPager adapter, viewPager fragments,  main layout and layout for items in list view, which is a fragment of a viewpager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not certain based on this snipit, but if you are trying to access an Android resource Id such as mentioned by the previous person, you need to use Android.Resource.Id in Xamarin.

If this is not what you want, I would ask if you have a FrameLayout inside your desired container with the id content_frame.

I designed my layout and include a FrameLayout which is what I switch in and out of using the SupportFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

```
Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new MainFragment();
        break;
    }
    if (fragment != null) {

        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fragmentManager = SupportFragmentManager;
        var transaction = fragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        // ----   change this line ---- //
        transaction.Replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        transaction.Commit();

        mDrawerList.SetItemChecked (position, true);
        SetTitle (mScreenTitles [position]);
        mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawer (mDrawerList);
    } else {
        Log.Error (this.Class.Name, "Error, fragment not created");
    }
```

Comment: You mean Resource.Id.content_frame? I'm using Xamarin.Android. Resource.id == R.id

Comment: Down-voting because it's not clear what the fix is. Can you add some further explanation?