# Should we add fragment to framelayout before calling replace method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm really sorry, but atm I can't test any code. But I have a question. How should we work with fragment manager? I got an error when I was trying to add fragmentA, then fragmentB, and then again A. I got an error : fragment is already added. And here is the question: should I call transaction.Add at launch and then replace it with others fragments or I shouldn't.
Thanks for attention and sorry for my English, it is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

You can add it if you want but you on first launch you can actually just use .replace even if there isn't a fragment currently loading into the frame and it will still work.

Comment: Then I just don't understand why my app crashes -_-. But thanks

Comment: If you add the code I can have a look at it for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30219007/fragmentmanager-crashes-when-using-replace